# Showing Logical Equivalence

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Show that $(\lnot(p\lor(\lnot p\land q))$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot p \land \lnot q$.

I am wondering what I did is correct. Very new to learning simple logic.

$$(\lnot(p\lor(\lnot p\land q)) \equiv \lnot((p\lor\lnot p)\land(p\lor q)) \\ \equiv \lnot(\text{T} \land (p\lor q)) \\ \equiv\lnot(p \lor q) \\ \equiv \lnot p \land 
\lnot q \\ \square$$

Comment: Seems good to me!

Comment: You can always build the truth table of both propositions and decide whether they match or not; if they match then, by definition, are equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only your last step is wrong:
$$\neg(p \lor q) \equiv (\neg p \land \neg q)$$

Comment: Thank you! I fixed my mistake and it should be good now, haha!

Comment: Yes indeed ! You may like this tool https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%C2%ACA%E2%88%A8%C2%ACB%E2%86%94%C2%ACA%E2%88%A7%C2%ACB

Comment: @DippyDog: That tool **does not work**!! Without looking at the code, I can't be sure why, but it fails on some of my FOL exercises, and the most likely reason is that the professor who wrote it did **not** really understand the correct tableaux method. (Many philosophy professors fall into this category, including in my university.)

Answer (score 4):

This is an alternative rount, and corrects for your misuse of DeMorgan's in the last step.

$$(\lnot(p\lor(\lnot p\land q))) \equiv \lnot p \land \lnot(\lnot p \land q)\tag{DeMorgan's}$$
$$\equiv \lnot p \land (p \lor \lnot q)\tag{DeMorgan's}$$
$$\equiv (\lnot p \land p) \lor  (\lnot p \land \lnot q)\tag{Distributive Law}$$
$$\equiv F\lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$$
$$\equiv \lnot p \land \lnot q$$

Comment: Whoops! I made an issue. I fixed it in my solution.

Comment: In the future, don't fix your post after other's provide corrections, because answerers are then chasing a moving target, and it render's answers meaningless to others.